# How can I view the table relations in PostgreSQL (if there is a foreign key column, what the primary key is...)?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Check information_schema.

Comment: Usually graphical SQL clients can display this kind of dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a command on another forum. `\d+ tablename` shows you the indexes and the foreign-key constraints.